# Add RESTful Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The source of my information is section 2.9 here:

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code][1]

What I'm trying to do is add a custom action "search" and corresponding view.

So, as it says to do in the documentation, I've added this code in my config/routes.rb file:

```
  resources :dimensions do
  collection do
    get "search"
  end
  end
```

I've also defined in the dimensions_controller file:

```
  def search
    @dimensions = Dimension.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @dimensions }
    end
  end
```

I then stopped and restarted the rails server, but when I navigate to /dimensions/home, I'm still getting this error message:

```
Couldn't find Dimension with id=search
```

Also showing that my parameter is:

```
{"id"=>"search"}
```

So am I just missing another bit of code that gives the instruction to interpret /dimension/search as a collection action as opposed to the show action?

I've already confirmed that search_dimensions_path exists, so I know that the resource block in the routes.rb file is actually adding paths. It's just interpreting them as a separate search action that's giving me trouble.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine. Can you show us your `routes.rb` file?

On a side note, you probably don't want to have a separate action for searching, using the `index` action is the preferred way.

Comment: But what if I want the index action to do something that isn't related to searching?

Comment: Like what? The `index` action should display a list of records. It might be `Dimension.all` or `Dimension.search(params[:query])`. It shouldn't be used for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

I had to make the resource declaration in my config/routes.db file for dimensions *after* creating the collection action, like so:

```
  resources :dimensions do
  collection do
    get "search"
  end
  end

  resources :dimensions
```

Then everything worked as expected.